# In 1 Thessalonians 1:10 what does it mean to "wait for his son from heaven"?

Tags: eschatology, 1-thessalonians

Paul commends the Thessalonians for being diligent:

> [1Th 1:3 NLT] (3) As we pray to our God and Father about you, we think of your faithful work, your loving deeds, and the enduring hope you have because of our Lord Jesus Christ.

So what does he mean that they were to "wait for his Son from heaven, whom he raised from the dead, even Jesus, which delivered us from the wrath to come"?:

> [1Th 1:10 KJV] (10) And to wait for his Son from heaven, whom he raised from the dead, even Jesus, which delivered us from the wrath to come.

Optional:

What does it mean that Jesus has "delivered us from the wrath to come"? What wrath?

Comment: Read Romans 1:18-32

Comment: @PerryWebb Who, what, when, where, why, how, etc. is "the wrath to come"? He has a specific "wrath" in mind: [Mat 3:7 NASB] (7) But when he saw many of the Pharisees and Sadducees coming for baptism, he said to them, "You brood of vipers, who warned you to flee from the wrath to come?

Answer (score 1):

First, the verb ἀναμένω (anamenó) means to await patiently (W E Vine); BDAG says it means "to wait for, expect someone or something".  It is a compound verb from "meno" to abide, and then made intensive by the addition of "ana" prefix.  It only occurs in 1 Thess 1:10 in the NT.

Greek has several words translated "wait" such as, "ekdechomai", "apakdechomai", "prosdechomai", "prosdokao", etc.

The meaning in 1 Thess 1:10 is clear as it is in the other places we are told to wait for the coming of Jesus, eg, James 5:7, 1 Cor 1:7, 2 Peter 3:12, Heb 10:37, Titus 2:13, etc.  That is, we wait for future glorious event.

The NT has numerous references to the future coming of Jesus in power and great glory in the clouds of heaven.  Matt 16:27, 24:30, 31, 38, 39, 42, 26:64, Mark 8:38, 13:26, 27, Luke 21:25-28, John 14:3, Acts 1:11, 1 Cor 1:7, 4:5, 11:26, Phil 3:4, 20, 1 Thess 1:9, 10, 3:13, 4:16, 17, 5:23, 2 Thess 2:1, 2, 8, Titus 2:12-14, 2 Tim 4:8, Heb 9:28, 10:25, 37, James 5:7-9, 1 Peter 2;12, 2 Peter 3:8-10, 1 John 2:28, 3:2, 3, Rev 1:7, 3:11, 22:12, 13, 20, 21, etc.

While faithful Christians eagerly await the coming of Jesus, it is dreadful time for the wicked; 2 Thess 2:8, Rev 6:15-17, 11:18, see 1 Cor 4:5, 2 Cor 5:10, Acts 17:31, John 12:48.  Jesus elaborated on this in several parables such as the parable of sheep & goats in Matt 25:31-46; and the parable of 10 virgins, Matt 25:1-13.  By contrast with the wicked, the righteous are elated at Jesus return, Isa 25:9.  That is, saved Christians do not fear judgement as Jesus explained in John 5:24, 25.  Thus, Jesus saved us from the wrath to come.

Comment: Can you describe what it entails to "wait for his Son from heaven"? How is it different from doing nothing?

Comment: I assume waiting for Jesus involves what He told us to do - "make disciples" (Matt 28:19 - the biggest task), "make every effort to be found spotless, blameless and at peace with him" (2 Peter 3:14), "to deny ungodliness and worldly desires and to live sensibly, righteously and godly in the present age" while we wait for the blessed hope (Titus 2:12, 13), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Christ is promised to come a second time unto salvation for the redeemed. This is the blessed hope which every Christian earnestly hopes for; for at that time, the dead in Christ are resurrected, we receive our immortal bodies, and we shall live forever with Christ never to die.

**1 Thessalonians 4:13-17**

> But I do not want you to be ignorant, brethren, concerning those who have fallen asleep, lest you sorrow as others who have no hope. For if we believe that Jesus died and rose again, even so God will bring with Him those who sleep in Jesus.
>
> For this we say to you by the word of the Lord, that we who are alive and remain until the coming of the Lord will by no means precede those who are asleep. For the Lord Himself will descend from heaven with a shout, with the voice of an archangel, and with the trumpet of God. And the dead in Christ will rise first. Then we who are alive and remain shall be caught up together with them in the clouds to meet the Lord in the air. And thus we shall always be with the Lord.

**1 Corinthians 15:51-53**

> Behold, I tell you a mystery: We shall not all sleep, but we shall all be changed— in a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trumpet. For the trumpet will sound, and the dead will be raised incorruptible, and we shall be changed. For this corruptible must put on incorruption, and this mortal must put on immortality.

Yet, His second coming is terror to the wicked. His glory lays low the kingdom of sin and all its citizens. The wrath to come is the destruction of the wicked at the second coming, and their final permanent annihilation after the thousand years.

**2 Thessalonians 2:8**

> And then the lawless one will be revealed, whom the Lord will consume with the breath of His mouth and destroy with the brightness of His coming.

**2 Thessalonians 1:9**

> These shall be punished with everlasting destruction from the presence of the Lord and from the glory of His power...

**2 Peter 2:6**

> and turning the cities of Sodom and Gomorrah into ashes, condemned them to destruction, making them an example to those who afterward would live ungodly;

For more on this, I recommend the Bible study [The Ultimate Deliverance](https://www.amazingfacts.org/media-library/study-guide/e/4985/t/the-ultimate-deliverance) from Amazing Facts. It will walk you through the various scriptures depicting the second coming of Christ and what takes place at that time. Secondarily, [Is The Devil in Charge of Hell?](https://www.amazingfacts.org/media-library/study-guide/e/4988/t/is-the-devil-in-charge-of-hell-) covers the topic of the final destruction of the wicked.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. What does Paul mean to "wait"? What does that involve? It might involve a lexicon (IE: like this: https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G362&t=KJV)

Comment: Wait generally denotes having patience and endurance. Thayer's lexicon says this word means "to await one whose coming is known or foreseen, with the added notion of patience and trust." This is the only place in the NT this certain word is used. That said, see also Luke 12:33-40, Phil 3:17-21, and Hebrews 9:27-28.

Comment: Can you please add your definition and any support for that view to your answer? Comments are just temporary, for clarifications. Thanks. And please elaborate on the cited passages rather than just say "see also". How are they relevant? Thanks again.

Comment: It is used 4 times in the LXX. At least 2 of the 4 are relevant, I should think.  https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/inflections.cfm?strongs=G362&t=KJV&ot=LXX&word=%E1%BC%80%CE%BD%CE%B1%CE%BC%E1%BD%B3%CE%BD%CF%89%CE%BD